# How To Add Looping Record To Textbox With MultiLine In VB

Tags: vb6

Can i add looping record to textbox with multiline in vb? 
Example : 
Table : Job
Field : NameJob
IT
Marketing
Sales
Designer

I want to put to textbox if i fill combo and choose Job so all of namejob in table job will add to textbox with format like this
- IT
- Marketing
- Sales
- Designer

Please give me idea? Thank's

Answer (score 0):

Sorry i already know the answer so i answered it. And sorry i'm not write the connection.

dim rsTemp as new adodb.recordset

set rsTemp = new adodb.recordset
rstemp.open "Select * From Job",cn, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly

do until rstemp.eof
     Dim StrData As String
     StrData = StrData & rstemp!NameJob & vbcrlf
loop

textbox1.text = Left(strData, Len(strData))